# Spreadsheet formula to count consecutive values in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, iwork-numbers

I have a column with "Y" and "N" values, and need a formula to count the last consecutive occurrences of "Y". So if I the column looks like this:

```
Y
Y
Y
N
Y
N
Y
Y
```

the desired result would be 2

```
Y
Y
Y
Y
N
N
Y
```

and here it would be 1

```
Y
Y
Y
Y
N
```

and here it would be 0.
Is this possible with things like Excel, Numbers or Google Docs?

Comment: Have you seen my solution to you problem? Could you give me some feedback?

Answer (score 2):

This little google apps script will make it happen:

```
function LASTCON(array) {
  // set active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get active sheet
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // get data  
  var data = sh.getRange(array).getValues();

  // determine length of array
  var dLen = data.length; 

  // create yes counter
  var yesCount = 0;  

  // itterate through array (backwards)  
  for(var i=dLen-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(data[i] == "Y") {      
      yesCount++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  // pass result to formula 
  return yesCount;
}
```

Add this script, via the script editor, to your spreadsheet and the function `LASTCON` is available throughout the worksheet, like so: `=LASTCON("A1:A6")`

See example file I've prepared: [Last consecutive values in a column](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdEo0V1diY2puOC1tbGRKbUhTVFJlZFE) (editable)